# Are ex-Politburo members protected from jail time in China?

Tags: china

Are ex-Politburo members protected from jail time in China? I am wondering to what extent Chinese high-ranking officials are protected from the law. To me, it seems like there's nothing as such and if there were it's kept informal and it's happening behind the scenes, and it's likely to change at any time since it's not written anywhere. Is my read correct or incorrect?

Answer (score 5):

Zhou Yong Kang, China's former chief security officer, was jailed for life in 2015 for corruption.

He's also seen as one of the chief rivals to Xi Jinpeng. So one might want to view this as Xi taking out one of his rivals.

But I think this would be a mistake akin to viewing the Biden administration wanting to take out Trump. I've no doubt a large section of the population in the USA see it this way nevertheless he was impeached twice by his peers and then, according to court evidence, instigated a riot/coup at Capitol Hill as well declaring the entire election "a fraud". This is corruption on a massive scale.

People do stupid things and high officials can do really seriously stupid things.

Answer (score 2):

As with **many** other questions by you, this one hinges on the [Rule of Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_law). There are reasons to believe that China is willing to break the letter of *their own* law if that suits the CCP, or to change it to legalize what the CCP wants to do.

Many autocracies are using the formal trappings of the law to justify and administer their policies, without respect for the ideal of the Rule of Law. For a good example, look at the protocols of the [Wannsee Conference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wannsee_Conference) and the turf battles between those who wanted genocide with all the i's dotted and t's crossed and those who wanted genocide without bureaucratic oversight. I'm not saying that Communist China is on the same level as Nazi Germany, even in [Xinjiang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uyghur_genocide), but it is clear that the CCP values economic development and national power/prestige over individual rights.

Ex-President Trump is *accusing* the current US government of breaking the Rule of Law to persecute him. Personally, I consider the fact that Trump is not in jail clear evidence that Trump is wrong in this regard.